# Remove Active Class on second click (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm using this great [accordion](https://codepen.io/rbobrowski/pen/likvA)  & it's working well. I've added an active class to the clicked items but I can't find a way to remove the active class if it's clicked a second time. I've tried adding it in a number of places, also added a separate click event which allows me remove any class but active.

```
var headers = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6"];

$(".accordion").click(function(e) {


 var target = e.target,
 name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

 $(target).addClass('active');
 $(target).siblings().removeClass('active');


 if($.inArray(name,headers) > -1) {
      var subItem = $(target).next();

      //slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
      var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
      var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion div").filter(function() {
           if($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
           return true; 
           }

      });

      $(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

      //slideToggle target content and adjust bottom border if necessary
      subItem.toggleClass('active').slideToggle("fast",function() {
           $(".accordion :visible:last").css("border-radius","0");
      });
      $(target).css({"border-bottom-right-radius":"0", "border-bottom-left-radius":"0"});

 }
});
```

Comment: toggle the class...

Comment: Now I feel pretty stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the first addClass to toggleClass fixes my issue.